# Query to select posts from that user. Facebook style

Tags: sql, facebook, session, asp-classic

I am trying to make a facebook style profile page but Ive hit a bit of a block.
Im sure Ill be kicking myself when I hear the answer but at the moment my minds a blank.
I have made a profile page and I thought I had it working but then I realized all the profiles were displaying the posts and info of the user currently logged on because Im using sessions, in the sql i had something like select * from users where session(ID) = user_Id, which was no good.
I have links on the users names in the newsfeed so when a user clicks that it goes to their profile but how?, What should the SQL look like, how do I get the user id of the name ive clicked and fill the profile page with their info?

any help is appreciated

thanks

heres the sql I used that used sessions

```
SELECT * 
FROM post INNER JOIN ubuser ON (post.pos_USERID = ubuser.usr_ID) 
WHERE "& session("ID") &" = ubuser.usr_ID 
ORDER BY pos_DATE DESC
```

Solved Thanks To Dan, For Anyone Else Who Is Looking For A Solution look into QueryStrings

Comment: What is the specific problem with your existing query?

Comment: nothings wrong with it, its working fine but its not what I want.
At the moment on say im logged in as user 1, if i go on my profile, all the detalis are right, all the posts on there are mine and the user info is right, but if i were to click on user 2's profile, because im using sessions all the posts and info on their profile is user 1's info.
I dont know how to get it to display the right info, i know its because im using sessions but i dont know what to replace it with.

Comment: hope it made sense haha.

Comment: Query parameters will help you with that.  They do other good things for you as well.

Comment: Thanks, Ill look into it now, is it Query String Parameters? because I just did a quick search on query parameters and it appears they are only used within access and not on the web?